# Function to search and sum a certain range by name of the respective column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table where new columns and rows of data will be added, but I want to do some calculations where certain intersections in this table have to be accessed. since the positions shift all the time, I do that with `INDEX(MATCH("RowName";"RowWithColumnNames";0)` . The entries in the first first column and row are identical (names of items): the matrix between them are numbers representing ratios between one particular and every other item.

To sum a range without adding the column name (row 1 in my case), I search the column with MATCH(), use it within ADDRESS() to get a starting and an end point, like this:

`=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2;MATCH($A3;$1:$1;0);4)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(200;MATCH($A3;$1:$1;0);4)))`

This, however, only returns 0. What am I doing wrong?

Here a picture since I feel like I may not be expressing myself that clearly:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try a combination on SUM, INDEX and MATCH functions.

- Format the data or range to sum to a table.
- Adapt the following formula where `Table1` is the name of your table.

```
=SUM(INDEX(Table1,0,MATCH(A4,Table1[#Headers],0)))
```

- Optionally, bring the formula down to fill the other cells.

When you add new data to the table, the sum will automatically be calculated.

[image]